# Game Package Update Architecture for iOS

Tags: ios

Since iOS does not allow the app to be recompiled outside. I wonder how can the multiplayer game develop updates, patches and download them into the game? Are they just resources, no codes at all, and all logics must precompiled and submit for review?
Would be thankful if you can kindly point out some directions, thanks

Answer (score 0):

You are right. Data packages like images, sounds, maps e.t.c. can be downloaded from your servers without actual app update, but all stuff done in code must be reviewed by Apple.

Also, there is a workaround - for example, in you have a script language for your game and can parse it with objC without app update, you can download new scripts and perform them in old .ipa. Just remember that it can be dangerous - if any of Apple rules will be violated with such "script update", app can be removed from appstore. I think, for in game stuff it will be ok. Good luck.